# AngularJS Date Not Appearing

Tags: json, angularjs, sql-server-2008, asp.net-web-api

My JSON date looks like: "DateofBirth":"1964-05-11T00:00:00"

But does not appear on the page.

Here is my HTML with AngularJS tags:

```
        <div id="dvEnrollees">
            <table id="tblEnrollees">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>EnrolleeNumber</th>
                        <th>FirstName</th>
                        <th>LastName</th>
                        <th>MiddleName</th>
                        <th>ProgramId</th>
                        <th>SSN</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>MaritalStatus</th>
                        <th>DateOfBirth</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody ng-repeat="Enrollee in Enrollees">
                    <tr ng-click="get(Enrollee)">
                        <td> <span>{{Enrollee.EnrolleeNumber}}</span></td>
                        <td> <span>{{Enrollee.FirstName}}</span></td>
                        <td> <span>{{Enrollee.LastName}}</span></td>
                        <td> <span>{{Enrollee.MiddleName}}</span></td>
                        <td> <span>{{Enrollee.ProgramId}}</span></td>
                        <td> <span>{{Enrollee.SSN}}</span></td>
                        <td> <span>{{Enrollee.Gender}}</span></td>
                        <td> <span>{{Enrollee.MaritalStatus}}</span></td>
                        <td> <span>{{Enrollee.DateOfBirth}}</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I can see the data in the response body, and all of the other fields appear properly, just not DateOfBirth.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using:

```
{{Enrollee.DateOfBirth}}
```

Instead of:

```
{{Enrollee.DateofBirth}}
```

Notice the lowercase "o" in "ofB..."

Comment: Glad to help. Please, mark the question as the correct one if it really helped you. Thanks :)